# Cannot use snap to install

Tags: snap

[image: sudo snap install microk8s --classic]

Why does it give me this error:

```
Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.
```

when I use the command:

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
```

even though I followed all the steps from the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

There's not much explanation beyond the error you are quoting.

**Snaps are not supported on WSL at this time.**

If you want to use snaps or if you want to have support for a desktop environment or GUI applications, you can install Ubuntu in dual-boot configuration or you can install Ubuntu in a VM like Virtual Box.